# Virtualbox OSX Host access to Ubuntu Samba share

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, samba

I am attempting setup of a dev environment using Virtualbox on OSX host running Ubuntu Server 16.10 on guest.
I am stuck on getting Samba to share the dev directory on the guest so that ultimately Netbeans can be used to edit the server files on OSX via the share directory.
This works fine on OSX to seperate physical Ubuntu machine.
From standard Samba config, at the end is

```
[testsharename]
path=/home/myusername/shared#note trailing slash required
#hosts deny=*
#hosts allow=192.168.0.210#ip of an allowed lan address
guest ok=yes
writeable=yes
```

The actual share is identified using Finder on OSX however on clicking on it there is an error that it cannot be found. Changing the share name reflects on Finder. The commented out lines are because I only really want a single Lan IP to access.

Finder error is that `the operation can't be completed because the original item for "testshare" can't be found`

Comment: Why not let Virtualbox set up and automount the share for you? Just select your VM in the Virtualbox GUI and click `Shared Drives` and share a Mac directory with the VM.

Comment: Because I want to mirror as close as possible the actual server environment - I do not want to serve files out of an OSX share, I want to serve for example webserver files from ONLY /var/www/ on the Ubuntu guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logs showed `Can't mount Samba share (canonicalize_connect_path failed)` therefore some research narrowed this down to a permissions issue hinted at by `https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1439582`

Moving the share out of the home directory into /var/www/ as I originally required (the home directory part was simply testing things) this, with 777 permissions on the share dir only showed it to work perfectly.
I certainly don't agree from the forum post that all path nodes leading to the share require permission changes however.